# How does the following code that sorts dictionary based on the values works in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following lists

```
Students=['student1','student2','student3','student4','student5','student6','student7','student8','student9','student10'] 

Marks = [45, 78, 12, 14, 48, 43, 47, 98, 35, 80]
```

I need to sort (by value) a dictionary with students as key and marks as values

I first converted  the above lists to

```
dictionary = dict(zip(Students,Marks))
```

Now I found this code online that does sort by values in descending order

```
for key, value in sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda item: item[1],reverse=True):
          print("%s: %s" % (key, value))
```

However, I do not understand how it works. I understand that in python you can initialize multiple variable in one line i.e x,y = 10, 20

But I'm not sure how these multi variables work in a for loop.If such a question has already been asked somwhere, please point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google for "tuple unpacking".

Answer (score 0):

Every student is mapped to a grade in the dictionary: `key` is the student and `value` is the grade.

The sorting is done using the lambda that is mapped to the `key` argument. `item[1]` is the grade, and it's sorted in reverse order which means higher first - lower last .

Answer (score 0):

```
You can consider it like: 

A = sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda item: item[1],reverse=True))
for key,value in A:
  print(key,value)
#key is a function that tells how you would want to sort the objects. 
#Here you use item[1] to sort which is marks values.
# reversed = True means sort according to marks in descending order
```